# How to encrypt configuration files for a desktop java application

Tags: java, security, encryption, javafx

I'm developing a desktop JavaFX application and plan on putting the database and server connection details into configuration files in a hidden folder on the windows machine.

The connection details will contain passwords. I know these should not be in plain text so how should I encrypt them so that only the application can read them?

I will try use a native installer to protect the source code.
Any advice on securing a java desktop app would be great, I really don't know much about security

Comment: You can't. Application needs to be able to get the plaintext password, user has access to the application, therefore user can access the plaintext password no matter what you do.

Comment: Ok so would it be better to place these config files on a server and have the application access these at start-up?

Comment: No, it would not help. If the application can access the config files, so can the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base of securely encrypting is that one secret is not stored on disk but only know by a user. If you cannot use that, you can only try *obfuscation*, that is all the information is there but much harder to read.

Here you could encrypt the data with a password *known by the application*, store pieces of the password in different variables, and then at run time:

- assemble the password
- read and decode the configuration
- erase the variable containing the password if that last operation is possible (unsure using plain Java)

But this will not protect the data from a user that is ready to analyse the Java bytecode, it will just require a very heavy work - that's why it is not security but just objuscation.

Comment: I think objuscation for strings in config files will be sufficient. I read that using a native installer would make the source code of the java application very difficult to retrieve or reverse engineer-is this true?

Comment: Security is just a matter of choosing an acceptable level in function of the expected risks (impact and occurence) and the involved constraints on application. If it is for sensitive data (bank operations) do not do that! If it is for the books in a school library, go ahead...

Answer (score 0):

Normal encryption would need a key (file) somewhere, and that is not too difficult.

However if you want to do it totally dynamically, without trace such a jar (zip format) which inside has some key file. Then use

```
Random random = new Random(42_424_242);
```

The Random constructor with a number selects a *fixed* random sequence, hence now you have got a sequence of numbers to encrypt/decrypte a byte sequence, say user xor-ing,

```
bytes[i] = (byte) (bytes[i] ^ random.nextInt(256));
```

Not unbeatable, but needs hacking.